# node.js - DatePicker jquery UI not workinng

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, node.js

I am trying to use JQuery UI datepicker in my node.js project and it doesn't work.

My simplified version of layout.ejs and index.ejs files.

layout.ejs

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>
<body>
      <script>
         $(function() {
            $( "#datepick" ).datepicker();
        });
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.ejs

```
<aside class="widget">
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepick"></p>
</aside>
```

Comment: "It doesn't work." but what exactly is the problem? What happens when you run it? Additionally, are these external js files successfully being imported?

Comment: When i click on date field i am not seeing the datepicker dialog. There are no external js files. I formatted the google cdn links for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/MfkAE/

Check your scripts source again, *better yet* change it to google link as I mentioend below; rest you can see it all works fine in demo with riight source.

Hope it helps! `:)`

**scripts**

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" media="all">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepick").datepicker();
});​
```

Comment: Those are google links which i edited for clarity. I am not sure why it is not working. Infact i tried my source code in JSFiddle before posting here and it works. I doesn't work only in my setup.

Comment: @Vinoth Aha; it must be something else then, do you want to check the console for any errors etc, lemme know I will remove this post if it was not helpful,

Answer (score 1):

the below code can be run in the EJS template engine with nodejs/express
Layout.ejs

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" media="all">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $('#datepick').datepicker();
    });
    </script>

</head>  
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Index.ejs

```
<aside class="widget">
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepick"></p>
```