# DatePicker jquery UI not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, ejs

I am trying to build my personal website using express and want to put a datepicker on one of the page.
I tried to change the ejs file of this page, however, nothing works.
I am wondering if it is because that the layout.ejs file exists, and wondering how can I just load jquery-ui in only of the ejs.file? Because I cannot find any related npm to install . Many thanks for answering！XD

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" media="all">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>  
<body>
    <script>
       $(function() {
           $( "#datepick" ).datepicker();
       });
    </script>

    <aside class="widget">
        <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepick"></p>
    </aside>
</body>
</html>
```

There is another similar question, but I think the answer does not works for me.
[node.js - DatePicker jquery UI not workinng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381289/node-js-datepicker-jquery-ui-not-workinng)

When I just use Express and change the index.ejs like the following, it works , but when there are many pages, it seems that it cannot be loaded...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$('#datepick').datepicker();
 });
</script>
</head>  
<body>

<aside class="widget">
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepick"></p>
</aside>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you including jQuery UI *twice*? And jQuery itself twice?

Comment: Because I am making sure if the JQuery-UI is loaded,so apart from using a local one, I also include one from the website....but it does not work either...

Comment: You're including jQuery 1.10.2, and then after that you're including jQuery 1.7.1, a substantially older version. Don't do that.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I just deleted them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[node.js - DatePicker jquery UI not workinng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381289/node-js-datepicker-jquery-ui-not-workinng)

For whom run into the same problem, this is the reference.

I finally found the answer by checking the code.I was unable to load JQuery for in the layout.ejs, I retyped the following in order to load the bootstrap, but actually by using https://npmjs.org/package/twitter-bootstrap-node twitter-bootstrap-node, there is no-need to load the javascripts again. This may be a common problems for beginners in Node.JS like me.Hope this answer can be helpful to people who run into the same problem and the code is in the answer of the related problem.

```
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/twitter/less/bootstrap.less"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi look at this jsfiddle link       http://jsfiddle.net/w7PHj/

you need to use like this....

```
    $('#datepick').datepicker();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I changed this in the according part and still could not work, I put this in HTML form and just open it, it works ....I am wondering if the code does not work for ejs and express? Many thanks!

Comment: add <script>  $('#datepick').datepicker(); </script> in head section and use appropriate javaScript files

Comment: Hi, this is what I do in a HTML file, it works <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link href="jquery-ui/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="jquery-ui/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
 <script>
  
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>

Comment: I am just wondering if this cannot be loaded in the Express and Node.js, wondering if your example do not use the express form and that is where my problem is, thanks !

Comment: $('#datepick').datepicker(); always use id or class with single quote not double quotetion in JQuery